# How to exclude a region from ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have functions `f[x]` and `g[x]` which are defined in the region `0 ≤ x ≤ 1` and `2 ≤ x ≤ 3`. If I want to plot either `f` or `g` separately, I can do the following:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3}, RegionFunction -> (! 1 < # < 2 &)]
```

However, if I now wish to make a `ParametricPlot` of `{f[x], g[x]}` then the above `RegionFunction` no longer works. The reason being that the `RegionFunction` not operates on the (f,g)-plane, and not on the parameter `x`. Moreover, `Exclusions` also seems to only work on isolated values of `x` and not a range.

Is there a way to achieve this in a single call to `ParametricPlot`? (I could do one `ParametricPlot` per connected region in the parameter range, then combine the graphics, but this is a bit of a pain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `#3` instead of `#`. See the `RegionFunction ->` docs, "Details" section-

```
f[x_] := Sin@ x
g[x_] := x^2;
ParametricPlot[{g@x, f@x}, {x, 0, 3}, RegionFunction -> (! 1 < #3 < 2 &), AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks and apologies for my oversight in looking through the docs.